# Vanilla JS Datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm trying to get Vanilla JS Datepicker to work :
https://github.com/mymth/vanillajs-datepicker

It's throwing an error: TypeError: undefined is not an object on e.dataset.date
That's an error down in the date picker code, so I'm not sure what's wrong.
Here's my callout in a function:

```
  function setDate() {
    console.log('DatePickerCk: ' , Datepicker);  // shows as 'class ue' - that doesn't seem right
    var cdate = $(mycell).attr('dc-oldval');
    console.log('CurDate: ' + cdate); // ok - 02/07/2020
    var dpelem = $(mycell).find('input');
    $(dpelem).val(cdate);
    console.log('ValofInput: ' , $(dpelem).val()); // ok - "02/07/2020"
    console.log('DpElem: ' , dpelem); // ok - hovering over it in console highlights the element in the DOM
    var datepicker = new Datepicker(dpelem, {
      autohide: true,
      daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
      daysOfWeekHighlighted: [],
      defaultViewDate: cdate,
      nextArrow: '>>',
      prevArrow: '<<',
      todayBtn: false,
      todayBtnMode: 1,
      todayHighlight: true
    });
    Datepicker.locales.en = {
      days: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
      daysShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      daysMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
      months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      today: 'Today',
      clear: 'Clear',
      titleFormat: 'MM y',
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      weekstart: 0
    }
  }
  setDate();
```

I see the date in the input, but the dropdown for the datepicker doesn't show.

Did I not call it correctly?  I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but what happens if you add [0] to your dpelem when setting up your Datepicker?  It looks like you're getting a jquery element vs a DOM element like it's probably expecting.

```
var datepicker = new Datepicker(dpelem[0]....
```

I don't really see anything wrong with your code otherwise.  I threw together a quick little [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8xwz5L4/) and it seems fine assuming you've got a valid reference to your input element.

Comment: OK @kman I changed to a DOM element and it's roughly working. Still don't see: (1) the Datepicker.locales.en working.  I tried putting 'XX' in for daysMin for 'Su' but it still shows as Su.  (2) Need to call some things after a new date is picked:  tried datepicker.hide{...} but throws errors - Not sure how to do stuff after DP is done.  Thanks.

Comment: I fixed (2) Still need a bit of help w/ (1)

Comment: you need to define the language options before wiring it up.  Just move your Datepicker.locales.en = {...} block before your var datepicker = new Datepicker(dpelem, {....} block.   Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7bzLwog/)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense & working now - thanks for the help.